# bash jq pass map as argument

Tags: bash, jq

I have this bash line containg jq that works fine:

```bash
kubectl --namespace=default get -o=json services | \
  jq 'del( .items[] |
           select(.metadata.name | contains("something","otherthing")))' | \
  jq '.items[].metadata.name' | \
  wc -l
```

And I would like to pass to `contains` many words. So I made a file named input.txt that contains these words and I am trying to pass this file to `contains` expression but with no luck:

```bash
kubectl --namespace=default get -o=json services | \
  jq -Rs --rawfile foo ./input.txt '
    del( .items[] |
         select(.metadata.name | contains($foo)))' | \
  jq '.items[].metadata.name' | \
  wc -l
```

...but this fails with  `jq: error (at <stdin>:7490): Cannot index string with string "items"`

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Consider editing your code sample so it _creates_ `input.txt` itself, and including an example that can substitute (for purposes of testing) as output of `kubectl`. Right now only people who run Kubernetes (or look up its documentation, and guess what output fitting that documentation your jq code is going to try to operate on) can test proposed answers to your question.

Comment: I _suspect_ you might want to split `$foo` into a list of words at newline boundaries, but right now that's only a guess; if I can't see something in the same format as your `input.txt` (and something in the same format as your kubectl output, and expected output given those two example inputs) I can't be sure. See the [mre] documentation in the Help Center.

Answer (score 2):

> Any suggestions please?

Apart from the suggestions made by @CharlesDuffy, first note
that assuming input.txt is a simple text file using "newline" as a delimiter of the relevant strings, then you'd want to gather those into a suitable JSON structure, such as an array:

```
 ($foo / "\n" | map(select(length>0))) as $ok
```

Next, if you wanted to check for equality, consider using `IN/1`, along the lines of:

```
select(.metadata.name | IN($ok[]) )
```

If you really want to use `contains`, then presumably you'd want something like:

```
select(.metadata.name as $name
| any($ok[]; . as $s | $name | contains($s)) )
```

Finally, you should consider combining your two invocations of jq into one.